# why alert is not show in web view in android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am making a demo .I run one url on android in other word I open one url in web view .on button click  "+" button I open one pop up screen which is open .But when ever user click out side the pop up screen it show a alert "you clicked out side".But when I check desktop browser in  it show alert .But when I open same thing it not show alert  why ?

here is url

http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3yG9E/9/show/

- 1) use "+" button to open pop up screen .click outside the pop up
  screen to show alert.

to check code here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3yG9E/9/

```
$(document).on('click', '#Cancel', function () {
    $("#AddButton").text('Add');
    $(".caseName_h").attr("readonly", false);
    $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
        transition: 'none'
    });
});
$('.ui-popup-screen').on('click', function () {
    alert('clicked outside popup');
});



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            web.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
        web.loadUrl("http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3yG9E/9/show/");


        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only set javascript enabled but also override `onJsAlert` of your `WebChromeClient` which you have to set yet for the webview.

Search for precise implementation this site.